# Kafka - 8 billion messages posted per hour

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to migrate a service that is on the mainframe to Kafka. The server was hosted on amazon (AWS).

Do I need to worry about something? Can the server not support it?

it will be a credit card transaction.

Comment: How big is each message? Is it uniform distribution over that time? Are you looking for Kafka cluster sizing requirements, or trying to determine if your existing cluster will handle it?

Comment: I don't know yet ... It's at the beginning of the project and I don't have these figures. I wanted to know for the moment if it is feasible.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some back of a napkin maths:

- 8 billion messages an hour is c.2 million a second (8000000000/60/60)
- If you assume 1 kB message size that's c.2GB per second

[This demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAAs4dvMXss) shows Kafka scaling to 2.7GB/s of ingress - so yes, Kafka can support it. You just need to scale and configure your brokers accordingly.